# Как посчитать количество слов где первая и последняя буква одни и те же?

Tags: java

```
package home1;
import java.util.*;
public class char_5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "cp1251"); 
System.out.println("Введите строку:"); 
String s = in.nextLine();
int i;
Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); 
for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)  {
char c = s.charAt(i);
if (map.containsKey(c)) { 
int t = map.get(c); 
map.put(c, ++t);  
} 
System.out.printf("Ответ: %c", c );
else { 
map.put(c, 1);          
} 
System.out.println("ответ: каждый символ встречается не менее двух 
раз.");
}
}
}
```

Comment: А что этот код вообще делает? Явно не то, что написано в заголовке.

Comment: В строке может быть несколько слов или сама строка и есть словом?

Comment: может быть целое предложение

Comment: Тогда просто делите предложение на слова с помощью сплита и регулярки на пробелы, а потом просто проверяйте совпадение первой и последней букв.

Comment: спасибо за идею)

Answer (score 2):

Реализация со Stream API

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "cp1251");
        System.out.println("Введите строку:");
        long count = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                .filter(x -> !x.isEmpty())
                .filter(x -> x.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase(x.substring(x.length() - 1)))
                .count();
        System.out.println("Результат: " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); // Читаем строку
String[] words = line.split("\\s+");             // Делим на слова
int count = 0;                                   // Изначальное кол-во совпадений
for (String word : words) {                      // Проходим по всем словам
    if (word.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == word.toLowerCase().charAt(word.length() - 1)) {
                                                 // Проверяем первую и последнюю букву
        count++;                                 // Увеличиваем, если совпадают
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

P.S. Если слово содержит только одну букву, его тоже посчитает.